# CW complex with no cells in dimension $n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Hi need some help with the following problem:

if $X$ is a CW complex with no cells of dimension $n$ then $\tilde{H}^n(X,G)=0$. where $G$ is any group.

thanx.

Comment: Seems like cell homology is the way to go.

Comment: thanx for sharing but can you provide more details! thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the homology groups using cellular homology?

Comment: thats the thing I'm struggling with the basics I guess!

Comment: The n-th homology is generated by the n-cells. But there are no n-cells...

Comment: so I need to obtain the chain complex, I think it depends on the cell structure right?? can you give an example on how to obtain a cell structure. thank you.

Comment: You only need (for this case) to know the definition of the n-th homology  as a quotient of cycles 
( meaning by the cycle group) by the  boundary group.

Comment: Actually, if the complex is orientable and n-dimensional, the top homology is not zero.

Comment: but this is not the case here.

Comment: Sorry, I need to be out for a while. Please see, e.g.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_homology  Do you know how to calculate the kernel of the map $d_n$ here? You just need to show it is zero, so your quotient is the zero group.

Comment: thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Sorry, I need to be out for a while. Please see, e.g.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_homology  Do you know how to calculate the kernel of the map $d_n$ here? You just need to show it is zero, so your quotient is the zero group. You have a quotient group that is zero, i.e., trivial. This can only happen in few ways: A/A, 0/B. Please let me know if you have a followup, I will look at it when I get back.

Answer (score 1):

The cellular chain complex is composed of sets of the form $H_n(X_n,X_{n-1})$. One can prove using excision and homotopy invariance that $H_n(X_n,X_{n-1}) = H_n(X_n/X_{n-1})$, where this last set is the wedge product of all the $n$ cells: 
$$
H_n(\bigvee_{\omega:\,\, n-\text{cell}} D_{\omega}^{n}/S_{\omega}^{n-1}) = \bigoplus_{\omega:\,\, n-\text{cell}}H_n(S_{\omega}^{n}) = \bigoplus_{\omega:\,\, n-\text{cell}}G
$$
Now, if there are no $n$-cells, then the direct sum is empty and thus the last term equals zero. Therefore $H_n(X;G) = 0$.

Comment: ok, thanks; but why is the direct sum is 0? also the question asks about reduced cohomology. is there a connection between them?

Comment: Ah... My bet, I definitely should read better... Anyway the direct sum is zero because there are no $n$ cells and its a direct sum over the $n$-cells. Unfortunately I haven't had cohomology theory yet, so I cannot tell whether there is a connection.

Comment: ah... my bad sorry!